# Pasehub: Extract data from the event url

Tags: parsehub

Need to extract data from the url that is provided as a link while parsing a template.
I have created a template for a website and it is working fine. But the link that is provided with each set of extracted object, I need to go to that particular link and also need the information for the same.
This should some way through Parsehub only. And I have multiple templates which I run at a go, so I do not want the details template to be created for each website detail object.

There should be a way that Parsehub could just give the details of the page url